# How to keep rows based on conditions of a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-conditions, date-difference

I have a df like below

```
VisitDate  FirstDate          ID       Dx
0  2018-04-16        NaT  7410013407  OtherPA
1  2018-05-15 2018-05-15  7410013407       PA
2  2018-05-15        NaT  7410013407  OtherPA
3  2018-05-24        NaT  7410013407  OtherPA
4  2019-11-02        NaT  7410022611  OtherPA
5  2019-11-05 2019-11-05  7410022611       OM
6  2018-05-15        NaT     8723458  OtherPA
7  2018-08-25        NaT     8723458  OtherPA
8  2018-09-10 2018-09-10     8723458       PA
9  2018-09-14 2018-09-10     8723458       PA
10 2018-12-07 2018-09-10     8723458       OM
11 2019-05-01 2018-09-10     8723458       OM
12 2020-08-06        NaT     8723458  OtherOM
13 2018-08-20        NaT     8723458  OtherOM

    df.to_dict(){
    "VisitDate": {
        0: Timestamp("2018-04-16 00:00:00"),
        1: Timestamp("2018-05-15 00:00:00"),
        2: Timestamp("2018-05-15 00:00:00"),
        3: Timestamp("2018-05-24 00:00:00"),
        4: Timestamp("2019-11-02 00:00:00"),
        5: Timestamp("2019-11-05 00:00:00"),
        6: Timestamp("2018-05-15 00:00:00"),
        7: Timestamp("2018-08-25 00:00:00"),
        8: Timestamp("2018-09-10 00:00:00"),
        9: Timestamp("2018-09-14 00:00:00"),
        10: Timestamp("2018-12-07 00:00:00"),
        11: Timestamp("2019-05-01 00:00:00"),
        12: Timestamp("2020-08-06 00:00:00"),
        13: Timestamp("2018-08-20 00:00:00"),
    },
    "FirstDate": {
        0: NaT,
        1: Timestamp("2018-05-15 00:00:00"),
        2: NaT,
        3: NaT,
        4: NaT,
        5: Timestamp("2019-11-05 00:00:00"),
        6: NaT,
        7: NaT,
        8: Timestamp("2018-09-10 00:00:00"),
        9: Timestamp("2018-09-10 00:00:00"),
        10: Timestamp("2018-09-10 00:00:00"),
        11: Timestamp("2018-09-10 00:00:00"),
        12: NaT,
        13: NaT,
    },
    "ID": {
        0: 7410013407,
        1: 7410013407,
        2: 7410013407,
        3: 7410013407,
        4: 7410022611,
        5: 7410022611,
        6: 8723458,
        7: 8723458,
        8: 8723458,
        9: 8723458,
        10: 8723458,
        11: 8723458,
        12: 8723458,
        13: 8723458,
    },
    "Dx": {
        0: "OtherPA",
        1: "PA",
        2: "OtherPA",
        3: "OtherPA",
        4: "OtherPA",
        5: "OM",
        6: "OtherPA",
        7: "OtherPA",
        8: "PA",
        9: "PA",
        10: "OM",
        11: "OM",
        12: "OtherOM",
        13: "OtherOM",
    },
}

df.dtypes
VisitDate    datetime64[ns]
FirstDate    datetime64[ns]
ID                    int64
Dx                   object
```

Each ID has one FirstDate.
 For each ID, I want to keep:

- All rows having PA or OM
- Rows having OtherPA, if Dx on FirstDate is PA AND VisitDate is within 30 days pre-FirstDate 
  For example: ID 8723458, Dx on FirstDate 10/09/2018 is PA 
  _row having OtherPA and VisitDate 25/08/2018 would be kept 
  _row having OtherPA and VisitDate 15/05/2018 would be removed
- Rows having OtherOM, if Dx on FirstDate is OM AND VisitDate is within 30 days pre-FirstDate

My expected result

```
VisitDate  FirstDate          ID       Dx
0 2018-04-16        NaT  7410013407  OtherPA
1 2018-05-15 2018-05-15  7410013407       PA
2 2018-05-15        NaT  7410013407  OtherPA
3 2019-11-05 2019-11-05  7410022611       OM
4 2018-08-25        NaT     8723458  OtherPA
5 2018-09-10 2018-09-10     8723458       PA
6 2018-09-14 2018-09-10     8723458       PA
7 2018-12-07 2018-09-10     8723458       OM
8 2019-05-01 2018-09-10     8723458       OM
9 2018-08-20        NaT     8723458  OtherOM
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because need distinguisg froup by `PA` and `OM` is extracted last 2 character in column `Dx` and get first non missing value in `FirstDate` column which is subtracted by `VisitDate` and filter values between `0, 30` days, last chain condition for all rows with `OM,PA` values in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
m1 = (df.groupby(['ID', df['Dx'].str[-2:]])['FirstDate']
        .transform('first').sub(df['VisitDate']).dt.days.between(0,30))
m2 = df['Dx'].isin(['PA','OM'])

df = df[m1 | m2]
print (df)
    VisitDate  FirstDate          ID       Dx
0  2018-04-16        NaT  7410013407  OtherPA
1  2018-05-15 2018-05-15  7410013407       PA
2  2018-05-15        NaT  7410013407  OtherPA
5  2019-11-05 2019-11-05  7410022611       OM
7  2018-08-25        NaT     8723458  OtherPA
8  2018-09-10 2018-09-10     8723458       PA
9  2018-09-14 2018-09-10     8723458       PA
10 2018-12-07 2018-09-10     8723458       OM
11 2019-05-01 2018-09-10     8723458       OM
13 2018-08-20        NaT     8723458  OtherOM
```

Details:

```
print (df['Dx'].str[-2:])
0     PA
1     PA
2     PA
3     PA
4     PA
5     OM
6     PA
7     PA
8     PA
9     PA
10    OM
11    OM
12    OM
13    OM
Name: Dx, dtype: object
```

Comment: Many thanks for your script and detailed explanation! It works perfectly well

Answer (score 1):

Try as follows:

```
cond1 = df['VisitDate'].sub(
    df.groupby(['ID',df['Dx'].str.replace('Other','')])['FirstDate']\
                            .transform('first')).dt.days.between(-30,0)

cond2 = df['Dx'].isin(['OM','PA'])

output = df[cond1 | cond2].reset_index(drop=True)

print(output)

   VisitDate  FirstDate          ID       Dx
0 2018-04-16        NaT  7410013407  OtherPA
1 2018-05-15 2018-05-15  7410013407       PA
2 2018-05-15        NaT  7410013407  OtherPA
3 2019-11-05 2019-11-05  7410022611       OM
4 2018-08-25        NaT     8723458  OtherPA
5 2018-09-10 2018-09-10     8723458       PA
6 2018-09-14 2018-09-10     8723458       PA
7 2018-12-07 2018-09-10     8723458       OM
8 2019-05-01 2018-09-10     8723458       OM
9 2018-08-20        NaT     8723458  OtherOM
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My result is slightly different as another filter is applied. For example, ID 7410022611 has Dx on FirstDate is OM, so any OtherPA of this ID would be removed, OtherOM within 30 days pre-FirstDate would be kept.

Comment: Right, my bad. Missed this additional constraint. Fixed it in the edit above. `output` should now completely match your expected output.